# Adding an overlay view to a text field in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add an overlay view to a UITextField in Swift (to add a Send button, etc.). The Apple API Reference for UITextField (and everywhere else on the Google) only shows how to do this in Objective-C (shown below). Can anyone show me how to do this in Swift, or point me to an updated API reference? Thanks in advance!

```
UIButton* overlayButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[overlayButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmark"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[overlayButton addTarget:self action:@selector(displayBookmarks:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
overlayButton = CGRectMake(0, 0, 28, 28);

// Assign the overlay button to a stored text field
self.textField.leftView = overlayButton;
self.textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Swift translated code would be

```
let overlayButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
overlayButton.setImage(UIImage(named: ""), for: .normal)
overlayButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(displayBookmarks(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
overlayButton = CGRectMake(0, 0, 28, 28);


// Assign the overlay button to a stored text field
self.textField.leftView = overlayButton;
self.textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Comment: CGRectMake() is no longer available in Swift. Use the cumbersome: 

`overlayButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24)`

Answer (score -1):

try this:

self.textField.addSubview(overlayButton)